# How should I do to declare a variable across different .d.ts files in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Just like

```
declare var demo {
    func_1();
}
```

in file1.d.ts and

```
declare var demo {
    func_2();
}
```

in file2.d.ts.

Then I want access both func_1 and func_2 in another ts file.

Hope someone help me~~~

Comment: .d.ts files are meant to define the type of a variable. Why would you want to define two different types for the  `demo` variable?

Comment: The original .d.ts file is provided by a develop frame, which means it will be modified frequently. But some basic functions or variables are not defined in it. I want use them without error messages and it is not so easy to modify the original file. Maybe some libraries providers have no idea about expansibility. :(

Comment: You can add new types in your own .d.ts file, and perhaps you can even overwrite existing type definitions, but a type can not have two definitions! How would the compiler know which definition to use when you use `demo` in your code?